# Crazy problems with data types and arrays in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsmutablearray, int, nsarray

I have a score stored in the global int variable. I wanted to add every new score to the array, every time game ends. So, code looks like this :

```
@implementation MainScene{
   NSInteger *_scorevalue;
    NSMutableArray *_scores;
}
```

In the didLoad method :

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_scores forKey:@"gameScores"];
```

Value of _scorevalue changes during the game (when objects collide, but it doesn't matter):

```
 _scorevalue=_scorevalue + 10;
```

When the game ends :

```
[_scores addObject:_scorevalue];
```

Xcode shows an issue here:"Implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type int to parameter of type id".

I tried to change _scorevalue type to float in the implementation (the same result,). But when I use NSNumber instead, issue near  `[_scores addObject:_scorevalue];` disappears, and new issue appears near `_scorevalue=_scorevalue + 10;`: "Arithmetic on pointer to interface NSNumber, which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform".

Can you explain it to me? How to fix that's all ?!

EDIT for Rob's answer:

Implementation :

```
NSInteger _scorevalue;
```

When the game ends :

```
  NSNumber *_scoreNumber= [NSNumber numberWithInteger:@(_scorevalue)]; // Xcode shows warning:
// "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending NSNumber to parameter of type NSInteger(aka // int)"
        [_scores addObject:_scoreNumber];
```

EDIT: As  nburk shows is better (no warnings):

`[_scores addObject:@(_scorevalue];)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSInteger *_scorevalue;
```

This is a pointer to an integer. You meant to just have an integer. Remove the `*`.

You also cannot add an integer into an `NSMutableArray`. You need to box it into an `NSNumber` such as `@(_scorevalue)`.

---

Note that this is not a good way to implement properties. Use `@property`:

```
@interface MainScene ()
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSMutableArray *scores;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, assign) NSInteger score;
@end
```

Get in the habit of accessing these through their properties: `self.scores` and `self.score`. Direct ivar access is not a good idea in ObjC, even with ARC.

Comment: Please, check the code in the edited question. And can you explain why better using property or maybe you have some good links for beginner to read?

Comment: ObjC has a number of features (such as KVO and lazy initialization) that are broken if you bypass the accessors (and this can lead to quite subtle bugs). You shouldn't use raw ivars except in init, in accessors, or when you have a specific requirement for it (usually related to C or C++ interfaces). As Apple says "it’s best practice for an object to access its own properties using accessor methods or dot syntax." For more, I highly recommend reading all of: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 0):

In your concrete, you can get around the errors to change the definition or your instance variables to:

```
@implementation MainScene{
   NSInteger _scorevalue;
   NSMutableArray *_scores;
}
```

and the adding to the array to:

`[_scores addObject:@(_scorevalue];)`

Note that by doing so, you are stroring `_scoreValue` as an object of type `NSNumber`, so when you retrieve it you need to call `integerValue` on that object, something like:

```
NSNumber *theScoreAsNumber = _scores[0];
NSInteger theScoreAsInteger = [theScoreAsNumber integerValue];
```